# Need an asymptotic function that's going to have a specific shape

Tags: functions, asymptotics

I'm looking for a function y = f(x) that grows quickly at first, and slowly later, asymptotically approaching 100.

I need it to hit certain specific points...

What I need is:

```
f(0) = 0
f(10) = 70
f(20) = 100
f( > 20) = 100 - I can cap this manually by capping the input, if necessary
f( < 0) = I don't care, it'll never happen in my use case
```

I know this probably should take the shape of:

```
y = 100 - e ^ (-ax + b)
```

Or something like that, but I have no idea how to find out the right coefficients to get it to have the shape I need.

Thank you!
Daniel

Comment: You may construct an interpolating polynomial function with your three values 0, 10 and 20. It may be helpful.

Comment: Ok, how would I do that? (sorry, math newbie here)

Comment: Do you want it to have zero slope at $x = 20$? Is it important that $f(x) \le 100$ for $0 < x < 20$?

Comment: Searching a solution for $y = 100 - e ^ (-ax + b)$ with $f(0)=0, f(10)=70$ (ignoring the $f(20)$ constraint) we get : $$f(x)=100\;\left(1-e^{\ln(0.3)x/10}\right)$$
(this gives $f(20)\approx 91$ with a smooth convergence of $f(x)$ to $100$ as $x\to\infty$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's construct an interpolating **polynomial** with the conditions:

- $ f(0) = 0 $
- $ f(10) = 70 $
- $ f(20) = 100 $

Since you want to set $f(x) = 100$ for $x > 100$ this condition will make it differentiable in $20$:

- $ f'(20) = 0 $

Also let $0$ be the point with the maximum growing rate. (This is just a guess and depends and what you really mean with "grows quickly at first". If you drop this condition then a polynomial of degree 3 will work. Comparison with bubbas answer: [$f''(0) = -\frac{1}{10} \neq 0 $ is not even visible to the eye.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%200.0000625%20x%5E4%20-%200.008125%20x%5E3%20%2b%207.75x,%20-1/200%20x%5E3%20-%201/20%20x%5E2%20%2b%208x,%20100,%2070%20from%200%20to%2020) )

- $ f''(0) = 0 $

Any polynomial that satisfies all this must at least have degree 4. So a sufficient approach is:

$ f(x) = a x^4 + b x^3 + c x^2 + d x + e $

$ f'(x) = 4a x^3 + 3b x^2 + 2cx + d $

$ f''(x) = 12a x^2 + 6b x + 2c $

With our conditions that leads to this system of linear equations:

$
  \begin{pmatrix}
         0 &    0 &   0 &  0 & 1 \\
     10000 & 1000 & 100 & 10 & 1 \\
    160000 & 8000 & 400 & 20 & 1 \\
     32000 & 1200 &  40 &  1 & 0 \\
         0 &    0 &   2 &  0 & 0 \\ 
  \end{pmatrix}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    a \\ b \\ c \\ d \\ e
  \end{pmatrix} =
  \begin{pmatrix}
    0 \\ 70 \\ 100 \\ 0 \\ 0
  \end{pmatrix}
$

The solution is:

$ f(x) = 0.0000625 x^4 - 0.008125 x^3 + 7.75x $

---

Lastly, to address the approach suggested in the question: $ f(x) = 100 - e ^{-ax + b} $ will not work, because it will never actually reach 100.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much! Especially for giving me the explanation of how you derived those coefficients, I was able to play with a linear solver and graphing it in excel, and ended up with the same equation shape, same solution, but slightly different numbers, which worked better for my case. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

How about
$$
f(x) = -\frac{1}{200}x^3 - \frac{1}{20}x^2 + 8x
$$
Its graph looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do [linear regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) on:

```
 log(100-y) = - ax + b
```

If only y wouldn't take the value 100.
The logarithm is then not defined.

So maybe try another constant than 100 in
your approximation. Or do a least square
[gradient search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent) to a more general function
with 3 parameters.

Bye